# I am trying to creat splash screen of bar app but i face this kind of error please tell me how to fix this kind of error in react-native

Tags: react-native

Splash(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

```
import React, { component } from 'react';
import {View, ImageBackground,Image} from 'react-native';
import { Component } from 'react';

var bg=require('./background.png');
var logo=require('./logo.jpg');

export default class Splash extends Component
{
    render()
    {
                 <ImageBackground
        source={bg}
        style={{height: '100%',width:'100%'}}
        >
            <View
            style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}
            >
                <image source={logo}
                style={{height:100,width:100}}></image>
            </View>
        </ImageBackground>

    }
}
```

Comment: you need to use ```return``` keyword in your ```render``` method. ```render``` must returns something. :)

Comment: like this: ```render() { return ... }```

Comment: can you share return code according above code thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need return keyword like this :

```
export default class Splash extends Component
{
    render(){
        return(
        <ImageBackground
        source={bg}
        style={{height: '100%',width:'100%'}}>
            <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
                <image source={logo}
                style={{height:100,width:100}}></image>
            </View>
        </ImageBackground>
        )

    }
}
```

Comment: <TouchableOpacity style={StyleSheet.btnLogin}>
                <Text style={style.text}>Login</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            
            </ImageBackground>
          );
    }
}
const style = StyleSheet.create({
  btnLogin:{
    width: 85,
    height: 45,
    borderRadius: 25,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.7)',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginBottom:20
  },
  text:{
    color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.7)',
    fontSize: 36,
    marginBottom:30,
    textAlign:'center'
  }

Comment: sir im trying to create button but only text appear on the  bottom screen no error show but no button show plz guide